# Parse command line arguments from config txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a function to parse command line arguments from a text file. This means each flag and value need to be returned as separate items in one array. Lines should be ignored if they are empty or start with `#`, `;` or `]`.

I am having multiple issues with my current function. First, splitting arrays inside the reduce function does not add arrays to the accumulator like using push would, but adds a new array to the accumulator. Second, strings inside quotes can be split into arrays even thought they should be treated as single arguments.

```js
const argsFile = `
# Command line arguments
--download example.com
--pass

--no-fail
--output "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New Folder"

--binary-location 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New Folder\\executable program.exe'
`;

let parsedArguments = argsFile.split(/\r?\n/)
    .filter(argument => (!argument.startsWith('#') && !argument.startsWith(';') && !argument.startsWith(']')))
    .reduce((a, c) => [...a, c.split(' ')])
    .filter(argument => argument !== '');
    
console.dir(parsedArguments)
```

This is the desired output for my function:

```
[
    "--download",
    "example.com",
    "--pass",
    "--no-fail",
    "--output",
    "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New Folder",
    "--binary-location",
    "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New Folder\\executable program.exe"
]
```

How can I modify my function to achieve the desired output? If there is a library that would handle this situation I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yargs seems to parse arguments for string quite robustly and it's rather configurable.

I came up with the following, which seems to yield the output you desired. Didn't test it with any other strings, however:

```
const parse = require("yargs-parser");

const argsFile = `
# Command line arguments
--download example.com
--pass

--no-fail
--output "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New Folder"

--binary-location 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New Folder\\executable program.exe'
`;

let parsedArguments = argsFile
  .split(/\r?\n/)
  .filter(
    (argument) =>
      !argument.startsWith("#") &&
      !argument.startsWith(";") &&
      !argument.startsWith("]")
  )
  .map((line) => {
    return parse(line, {
      string: true,
      configuration: {
        "boolean-negation": false,
        "camel-case-expansion": false,
      },
    });
  })
  .map((ar) => {
    delete ar._;
    let properties = Object.keys(ar);
    if (properties.length == 0) return [];
    return [
      "--" + properties[0],
      typeof ar[properties[0]] == "boolean" ? "" : ar[properties[0]],
    ];
  })
  .filter((argument) => argument.length != 0);

let flatArgs = [].concat.apply([], parsedArguments).filter((i) => i != "");

console.dir(flatArgs);
```

Yields the following:

```
[ '--download',
  'example.com',
  '--pass',
  '--no-fail',
  '--output',
  'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New Folder',
  '--binary-location',
  'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New Folder\\executable program.exe' ]
```

Yargs parser parses the string "too aggressively" for your particular requirements, that's why we have to do the mapping with kinda reversing what parser has done (prepending with '--', ignoring booleans etc.). Then, at the end, we have to "flatten" the array, as each line is being parsed to its own array.

**Edit**: so, if we've to take care of short args as well, yargs will not really be suitable as we do not have an access to raw string after parsing. We could make use of yarg's internal function which tokenizes the string, however (I only had to transpile it to js):

```
function tokenizeArgString(argString) {
    if (Array.isArray(argString)) {
        return argString.map(e => typeof e !== 'string' ? e + '' : e);
    }
    argString = argString.trim();
    let i = 0;
    let prevC = null;
    let c = null;
    let opening = null;
    const args = [];
    for (let ii = 0; ii < argString.length; ii++) {
        prevC = c;
        c = argString.charAt(ii);
        // split on spaces unless we're in quotes.
        if (c === ' ' && !opening) {
            if (!(prevC === ' ')) {
                i++;
            }
            continue;
        }
        // don't split the string if we're in matching
        // opening or closing single and double quotes.
        if (c === opening) {
            opening = null;
        }
        else if ((c === "'" || c === '"') && !opening) {
            opening = c;
        }
        if (!args[i])
            args[i] = '';
        args[i] += c;
    }
    return args;
}


const argsFile = `
# Command line arguments
--download example.com
--pass

--no-fail
--output "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New Folder"

-a test
--binary-location 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New Folder\\executable program.exe'
`;

let parsedArguments = argsFile.split(/\r?\n/)
    .filter(argument => (!argument.startsWith('#') && !argument.startsWith(';') && !argument.startsWith(']')))
    .map(line => tokenizeArgString(line))
    .filter(argument => argument.length != 0);

let flatArgsNoQuotes = [].concat.apply([], parsedArguments).map(args => args.replace(/['"]+/g, '')).filter(i => i != "");
    
console.dir(flatArgsNoQuotes)
```

Comment: In what way does yargs parse the string too aggressively? As for prepending with `--`, this is my fault but there can also be arguments that start with a single `-` like `-a file.txt`.

Comment: *Parses too aggresively for your requirements*, as any standard parser will get rid of the hyphens, yet you need them. Okay, we have to take care of single hyphen args, anything else? There's no such argument in your original example, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Nostupidquestions edited the answer a bit so that short args are being taken into account as well.

Comment: I believe single args is the only other thing. I am trying to recreate the functionality of the parser from the youtube-dl --config-location option. https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/search?q=--config-location&unscoped_q=--config-location